# using awk or other shell command inside gnuplot function

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I want something like this:

```
file1='logs/last/mydata1.log'
file2='logs/last/mydata2.log'

# declare function that uses awk to reshape the data - does not work :(
sum1(fname)=("<awk '{sum=0; for(i=8;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1,sum/2}' $fname")
sum2(fname)=("<awk '{sum=0; for(i=9;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1,sum/2}' $fname")

# plot different columns of my file and awk processed file
plot file1 u 1:2 title "thing A measure 1" w l, \
     file1 u 3:4 title "thing A measure 2" w l, \
     file2 u 1:2 title "thing B measure 1" w l, \
     file2 u 3:4 title "thing B measure 2" w l, \
     sum1(file1) u 1:2 title "group A measure 1" w l, \
     sum2(file1) u 1:2 title "group A measure 2" w l, \
     sum1(file2) u 1:2 title "group B measure 1" w l, \
     sum2(file2) u 1:2 title "group B measure 2" w l
```

What is not working is the part with `awk` inside a gnuplot function.
Using my `awk` script directly after `plot` works fine:

```
plot "<awk '{sum=0; for(i=9;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1,sum}' ./logs/last/mydata1.log" u 1:2 w l
```

Is there a way to put `awk` or other shell commands inside a gnuplot function?
I know I could outsource the awk script to another file and awk this file directly after `plot`, but I don't want separate files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$var` doesn't expand `var` in a string within gnuplot like it would in a shell.  You want to use gnuplot's string concatenation (which uses the `.` operator):

```
sum1(fname)="<awk '{sum=0; for(i=8;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1,sum/2}' ".fname
```

Or, I suppose you could use `sprintf` if you find that more comfortable:

```
sum1(fname)=sprintf("<awk '{sum=0; for(i=8;i<=NF;i+=2) sum+=$i; print $1,sum/2}' %s",fname)
```

*Note that this doesn't actually execute the command.  It just builds the string which will be passed to `plot` and then `plot` will execute the command.  If you actually want to execute a command in a function, you can call `system` as a function.  From the docs:

```
`system "command"` executes "command" using the standard shell. See `shell`.
 If called as a function, `system("command")` returns the resulting character
 stream from stdout as a string.  One optional trailing newline is ignored.

 This can be used to import external functions into gnuplot scripts:

       f(x) = real(system(sprintf("somecommand %f", x)))
```

Comment: Perfect! I now also added another helper function
`exec(cmd,arg1)=(system(sprintf(cmd, arg1)))`
which relieves me from retyping `system(sprintf())` several times

Comment: I just saw that my `exec` does not work with `plot`. As you said, `plot` expects a string, as produced by your second snippet. Thx for pointing that out.