# Plotting a function directly from a text file

Tags: awk, gnuplot

Is there a way to plot a function based on values from a text file?

I know how to define a function in gnuplot and then plot it but that is not what I need.
I have a table with constants for functions that are updated regularly. When this update happens I want to be able to run a script that draws a figure with this new curve. Since there are quite few figures to draw I want to automate the procedure.

Here is an example table with constants:

```
location a  b  c
1        1  3  4
2
```

There are two ways I see to solve the problem but I do not know if and how they can be implemented.

1. I can then use awk to produce the string: `f(x)=1(x)**2+3(x)+4`, write it to a file and somehow make gnuplot read this new file and plot on a certain `x` range.
2. or use awk inside gnuplot something like `f(x) = awk /1/ {print "f(x)="$2` etc., or use awk directly in the plot command.

I any case, I'm stuck and have not found a solution to this problem online, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you looking for a 1-line solution?

Comment: When I use `gnuplot`, I always call it from inside of `Perl`. If this is not an option for whatever reason, I would recommend calling `awk` from inside of your `gnuplot` script. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846717/using-awk-or-other-shell-command-inside-gnuplot-function) and [here](http://security.riit.tsinghua.edu.cn/~bhyang/ref/gnuplot/datafile3-e.html) for ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I think the description of the problem is not very precise, specifically how the sample text file is going to interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibilty to have a somewhat generic version for this, you can do the following:

Assume, the parameters are stored in a file `parameters.dat` with the first line containing the variable names and all others the parameter sets, like

```
location a b c
1        1 3 4
```

The script file looks like this:

```
file = 'parameters.dat'
par_names = system('head -1 '.file)
par_cnt = words(par_names)

# which parameter set to choose
par_line_num = 2
# select the respective string
par_line = system(sprintf('head -%d ', par_line_num).file.' | tail -1')
par_string = ''
do for [i=1:par_cnt] {
  eval(word(par_names, i).' = '.word(par_line, i))
}
f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c

plot f(x) title sprintf('location = %d', location)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question ([gnuplot store one number from data file into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211339/gnuplot-store-one-number-from-data-file-into-variable)) had some hints for me in the first answer.

In my case I have a file which contains parameters for a parabola. I have saved the parameters in gnuplot variables. Then I plot the function containing the parameter variables for each timestep.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

datafile = "parabola.txt"

set terminal pngcairo size 1000,500
set xrange [-100:100]
set yrange [-100:100]
titletext(timepar, apar, cpar) = sprintf("In timestep %d we have parameter a = %f, parameter c = %f", timepar, apar, cpar)

do for [step=1:400] {
  set output sprintf("parabola%04d.png", step)

  # read parameters from file, where the first line is the header, thus the +1
  a=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $1}' " . datafile)
  c=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $2}' " . datafile)

  # convert parameters to numeric format
  a=a+0.
  c=c+0.

  set title titletext(step, a, c)

  plot   c+a*x**2
}
```

This gives a series of png files called parabola0001.png,
parabola0002.png,
parabola0003.png,
…, each showing a parabola with the parameters read from the file called `parabola.txt`. The title contains the parameters of the given time step.

For understanding the gnuplot `system()` function you have to know that:

- stuff inside double quotes is not parsed by gnuplot
- the dot is for concatenating strings in gnuplot
- the double quotes for the awk `printf` command have to be escaped, to hide them from gnuplot parser

To test this gnuplot script, save it into a file with an arbitrary name, e.g. `parabolaplot.gplot` and make it executable (`chmad a+x parabolaplot.gplot`). The `parabola.txt` file can be created with

`awk 'BEGIN {for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) printf "%f\t%f\n", i/200, i/100}' > parabola.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/1/ {print "plot "$2"*x**2+"$3"*x+"$4}' | gnuplot -persist
```

Will select the line and plot it

Answer (score 0):

This was/is another question about how to extract specific values into variables with gnuplot (maybe it would be worth to create a Wiki entry about this topic).
There is no need for using `awk`, you can do this simply with gnuplot *only* (hence platform-independent), even with gnuplot 4.6.0 (March 2012).
You can do a `stats` (check `help stats`) and assign the values to variables.

**Data:** `SO15007620_Parameters.txt`

```
location a  b  c
1        1  3  4
2       -1  2  3
3        2  1 -1
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### read parameters from separate file into variables
reset

FILE = "SO15007620_Parameters.txt"

myLine = 1     # line index 0-based
stats FILE u (a=$2, b=$3, c=$4) every ::myLine::myLine nooutput

f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c

plot f(x) w l lc rgb "red" ti sprintf("f(x) = %gx^2 + %gx + %g", a,b,c)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]