# In Gnuplot, how to plot a function many times on the same plot in a for loop

Tags: plot, gnuplot

In gnuplot, I'm trying to plot a function with 5 parameters, whose values are stored in an external file, 8 times on the same graph. I want to plot the vapor pressure of 8 species as a function of temperature; the vapor pressure is parametrized by 5 variables. I have tried using a `do-for` loop, but that only plots one species. How can I plot the function 8 times on the same plot using the 8 sets of parameters? The code below is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841152/2449192), and works except that the answer as given will print 8 pngs, but I would like 1, and modified it in my attempt to do so.

`parameters.txt`

```
A   B   C   D   E
33.634  -3647.9 -8.6428 -9.69E-11   1.19E-06
19.419  -5869.9 -0.4428 -1.26E-02   5.22E-06
-15.077 -4870.2 14.501  -3.16E-02   1.35E-05
76.1    -5030   -25.078 9.76E-03    -2.58E-13
2.1667  -2631.8 4.035   -1.18E-02   6.10E-06
39.917  -4132   -10.78  1.97E-10    2.04E-06
29.89   -3953.5 -7.2253 2.11E-11    8.96E-07
99.109  -7533.3 -32.251 1.05E-02    1.23E-12
```

`vapor.plt`

```
reset
datafile = "parameters.txt"

set terminal pngcairo
set xrange [273.15:493.15]
set logscale y
set output "vapor.png"
do for [step=1:8] {
    # read parameters from file, where the first line is the header, thus the +1
    a=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $1}' " . datafile)
    b=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $2}' " . datafile)
    c=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $3}' " . datafile)
    d=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $4}' " . datafile)
    e=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $5}' " . datafile)

    # convert parameters to numeric format
    a=a+0.
    b=b+0.
    c=c+0.
    d=d+0.
    e=e+0.

    plot 10**(a + b/x + c*log10(x) + d*x + e*x**2) title ''
}
set output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot several function into one graph, you must either use only one `plot` command, and separate the functions with commas:

```
plot f(x), g(x), h(x)
```

This would plot all three function in one graph. For your case you would need to extract the parameters first to have `a1`, `a2`,... `a8` etc. This would have the advantage, that you could have a key (legend) for the parameter sets.

The second option fits better to your existing script. You need to put the `plot` calls in a `multiplot`:

```
reset
datafile = "parameters.txt"

set terminal pngcairo
set xrange [273.15:493.15]
set logscale y
set output "vapor.png"

set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set multiplot
do for [step=1:8] {
    # read parameters from file, where the first line is the header, thus the +1
    a=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $1}' " . datafile)
    b=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $2}' " . datafile)
    c=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $3}' " . datafile)
    d=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $4}' " . datafile)
    e=system("awk '{ if (NR == " . step . "+1) printf \"%f\", $5}' " . datafile)

    # convert parameters to numeric format
    a=a+0.
    b=b+0.
    c=c+0.
    d=d+0.
    e=e+0.

    plot 10**(a + b/x + c*log10(x) + d*x + e*x**2) lt step title ''

    if (step == 1) {
        unset border
        unset xtics
        unset ytics
    }
}
unset multiplot
set output
```

With `multiplot` the border and tics would be redrawn each time, which looks ugly (bolder). For this I unset border, xtics and ytics after the first plot. But in order to have the same margins for all plots I set fixed, absolute margins at the beginning. It would be possible to hold the automatic margins, which are computed with the first plot, but that is a bit lengthy (see the topic 'Gnuplot-defined variables' in the docs).

I also used different linetypes for every plot. The above script gives the output:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I did not know that multiplot would "append" plots if you did not give it a grid pattern to put the different plots on.