# Assign a value to a gnuplot function out of a data file

Tags: awk, gnuplot

In Gnuplot, I try to assign a value to a function f(x) from a two column data file in order to plot that function as a horizontal line.

```
f(x)=value of $2 at $1==2 from filename.dat
plot 'filename.dat' , ' ' x<=2?f(x):1/0
```

I tried :

```
awk '$1==2,print{$2}' filename.dat
```

but it says :

> Warning: encountered a string when expecting a number
>            Did you try to generate a file name using dummy variable x or y?".

Any suggestions?

P.S.: I know that there should be a `<` sign after awk, but it would not display it here.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18583180/2604213 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/15007620/2604213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this approach:

```
filename = "test.txt"
y = system(sprintf("awk '$1==2{print $2}' %s", filename))
f(x)=real(y)
plot filename u 1:2 w l, f(x) t ''
```

It seems that gnuplot is interpreting the value of `y` as a string. Therefore, we have to enforce a conversion to a number, which I do by converting it to a `real` number. (Another possibility `f(x)=y+0`)

Here is the ouput for my demo `test.txt` with the following content:

```
1 1
2 0.5
3 0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not think it would be that easy, but every time you search for "basic" stuff like this, it is always stumbling upon very advanced stuff. Do you know a place where I can get more basic information about awk like this one ??

Comment: @PaulRousseau: Glad that I could help. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark the question answered.  
For more information an awk see [Awk by example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-awk1/) or the [Awk Introduction Tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/)